# As better to build a database structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

which is better 500 tables with 50 entries, or 1 table with 25,000 records?

InnoDB, MySQLi

Very bad if I have 500 tables for recording? or nothing to worry about?

```
Table1[id,caption,spec,desc]
Table2[id,caption,spec,desc]
Table...[id,caption,spec,desc]
Table499[id,caption,spec,desc]
```

Comment: What are you doing with the data?

Comment: No reason to have 500 tables. It will just make your queries harder.

Comment: if your DB has trouble handling 25,000 records, I'd suggest upgrading your server to something better... 25k records is **NOTHING** for a properl RDBMS. You can partition a table into distinct physical storage units later, if a table's size DOES become a peformance issue. But right now you're worrying about something that is NOT a problem... unless your db server is an 8088-4.77mhz dinosaur.

Comment: @MarcB I've made much more with InnoDB, this question I guess it's falling into premature optimization category.

Comment: Imagine your code managing 500 tables.... Imagine yourself writing code to find a record in 500 tables against 1 table...

Comment: And if your table names contain numbers -  you alomost every time do something wrong.

Comment: I use only a few tables while using the program, why should I run every time the sample data? and I do not need help

Comment: Splitting the table into 500 tables is planned suicide, not premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

25,000 records is easy for mysql to handle, especially if it's properly indexed.

500 of the same table is likely going to be a headache to manage.

If you have to go with the 500 table solution, you could consider going MyISAM and putting a merge table over it.

Comment: Care to explain? Otherwise this is if anything a comment

Comment: I think this is an acceptable answer.  He indicates that it would be better to use 1 table, by both saying that MySQL has no trouble with a table this size and that it is a headache to manage 500 tables.  He then provides some advice for optimization if going against his recommendation.  Why the downvotes on this answer?  This is exactly the question the OP asked.